# What is the highest g planet that can be escaped with current rocketry technology?

Tags: hard-science, spaceships, gravity, rockets

A spacefaring race in my story evolved on a high g planet. This made them smaller, stockier and stronger than most other spacefarers. The question is just how high their planet’s gravity could be while still allowing them to lift payloads into orbit (and from there employ the handwavium drive that only works in 0g). I get the feeling Earth is already pushing it in terms of escapability, but I can’t find where I read that, and I haven’t had to do rocket science in a long time!

Their planet has an atmosphere similar in density to Earth (I’m going to munge together the exact composition later), so just assume atmospheric thickness/drag etc is the same as ours for the purposes of this question. You can also assume (for the sake of ease) that the planet is Earth sized with a dense Unobtanium core. If it matters, assume the minimum payload weight is at least 150 kilograms.

Given current rocket technology, the tyranny of the rocket equation, and known material science:

How high can gravity get before this species can’t get to space?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117347/225215

Comment: If all they need for the magical drive is imponderability a.k.a. weightlessness, then they can simply mount the drive on an airplane and arrange for a [free fall trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced-gravity_aircraft). (Typically, such maneuvers provide for about half a minute of wightlessness.) Or just push the craft off a really high tower. Otherwise, if you really mean "almost no gravitational field" then I'm afraid that they must go really really far into interstellar space.

Comment: @AlexP: The handwavium drive is a low impulse reactionless engine. Or a hyperspace drive that only functions in areas with a high Plot quotient. Or a wormhole generator that needs a long time to spool up. For the purposes of this question it’s mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @BMF Highly related and very useful! I just need the other half of ‘what can we actually build’ to solve for g.

Comment: @JoeBloggs that question may be useful, but I was actually trying to find this one: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14383/29727

Comment: @BMF: That is almost exactly the question/answer I need, not sure how I missed it. Still misses any info on the hard engineering challenges, but I feel like I’ve at least got a place to start now. It also makes a good point about the square/cube relationship of fuel to thrusters, which I feel is going to be a major limiting factor.

Comment: Short version, above 10g is basically impossible because the mass of the rocket approaches an appreciable mass fraction of the planet it's launching from. Realistically, and taking today's best (non-nuclear) technology, I'd ballpark the practical limit at  somewhere around 2.5 g. If you have infinite funding and the entire world dedicates themselves to building a big rocket, 4g or *maybe* 4.5g would be possible, but the rocket would cost trillions to place a single ton into orbit. Generally though, I think rocketry is the wrong approach beyond 2.5g and alternatives should be investigated.

Comment: @Dragongeek: Pretty much, though it’s a much more general question as it has no restrictions on radius/atmosphere. That 10g limit came from the second link BMF provided by the way. All very useful stuff, and I wish I’d searched SE for ‘size’ instead of ‘mass’, since id have found that question if I had!